# A squarred variable is outside the index

Tags: python, pandas

A variation of this post, without the detailed traceback, had been posted in the SO about two hours ago. This version contains the whole traceback.)

I am running StatsModels to get parameter estimates from ordinary least-squares (OLS). Data-processing and model-specific commands are shown below. When I use import statsmodels.formula.api as smas the operative api, the OLS works as desired (after I drop some 15 rows programmatically), giving intuitive results. But when I switch to import statsmodels.api as sm as the binding api, without changing the code almost at all, things fall apart, and Python interpreter triggers an error saying that 'inc_2 is not in the index'. Mind you, inc_2 was computed after the dataframe was read into StatsModels in both model runs: and yet the run was successful in the first, but not in the second. (BTW, p_c_inc_18 is per-capita income, and inc_2 is the former squarred. inc_2 is the offensive element in the second run.)

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import statsmodels.api as sm 
%matplotlib inline import 
matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns 
sns.set(style="whitegrid") eg=pd.read_csv(r'C:/../../../une_edu_pipc_06.csv') pd.options.display.precision = 3 
plt.rc("figure", figsize=(16,8)) 
plt.rc("font", size=14) 
sm_col = eg["lt_hsd_17"] + eg["hsd_17"] 
eg["ut_hsd_17"] = sm_col 
sm_col2 = eg["sm_col_17"] + eg["col_17"] eg["bnd_hsd_17"] = sm_col2 
eg["d_09"]= eg["Rate_09"]-eg["Rate_06"] 
eg["d_10"]= eg["Rate_10"]-eg["Rate_06"] inc_2=eg["p_c_inc_18"]*eg["p_c_inc_18"] 
X = eg[["p_c_inc_18","ut_hsd_17","d_10","inc_2"]] 
y = eg["Rate_18"] 
X = sm.add_constant(X) 
mod = sm.OLS(y, X) 
res = mod.fit()
print(res.summary())
```

Here is the traceback in full.

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-e2f4d325145e> in <module>
     17 eg["d_10"]= eg["Rate_10"]-eg["Rate_06"]
     18 inc_2=eg["p_c_inc_18"]*eg["p_c_inc_18"]
---> 19 X = eg[["p_c_inc_18","ut_hsd_17","d_10","inc_2"]]
     20 y = eg["Rate_18"]
     21 X = sm.add_constant(X)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2804             if is_iterator(key):
   2805                 key = list(key)
-> 2806             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
   2807 
   2808         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)
   1550             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
   1551 
-> 1552         self._validate_read_indexer(
   1553             keyarr, indexer, o._get_axis_number(axis), raise_missing=raise_missing
   1554         )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1644             if not (self.name == "loc" and not raise_missing):
   1645                 not_found = list(set(key) - set(ax))
-> 1646                 raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
   1647 
   1648             # we skip the warning on Categorical/Interval

KeyError: "['inc_2'] not in index"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  Your posted code will not run elsewhere, includes input overhead, and does not exhibit the problem structure.

Comment: Please update your post with these details.  As you can see when you attempted to comment on my answer, comments are not suitable for code.  From the readable portions, it appears that `inc_2` is not an index that exists in `eg`; you need to repair that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you used insists that a list of strings is a legal index into `eg`.  If you `print(eg)`, you'll see that it has no such element.  I think what you meant was to make a list of elements, each indexed by a single string.

```
X = [
      eg["p_c_inc_18"],
      eg["ut_hsd_17"],
      eg["d_10"],
      eg["inc_2"]
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks.  I re-ran model, after revising code per your comments.  Error persists.

Comment: Thanks.  I re-ran model per code per your comments.  Error persists. `KeyError`                                  `Traceback` 
-> `2646`                 `return self._engine.get_loc(key)`
   `2647`             `except KeyError:`
`During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`
                                
`<ipython-input-1-802920d04782>` `in <module>`
     `17 eg["d_10"]`= `eg["Rate_10"]-eg["Rate_06"]`
     `18 inc_2`=`eg["p_c_inc_18"]*eg["p_c_inc_18"]`
---> `19 X` = `[eg["p_c_inc_18"]`,`eg["ut_hsd_17"]`,`eg["d_10"]`,`eg["inc_2"]]`
     `KeyError`: `'inc_2'`